# How to automate video playback on an android app with appium

Tags: android, video, automation, appium

So, I am trying to automate an android app that provides media content on OTT, say like netflix.

Now the automation tool I am using is Appium with java.

Rest of the app automation is working just fine with me. However, I am unable to validate the video playback. As soon as the video player is launched, the UI automator is unable to fetch the screenshot of the device. In order to counter that, I got the object ids of the controls like "play","seekbar" etc from the player xml file created by the development team.

However, even after that if I try to run my script, I always get a NoSuchElement Exception.

Did I mention, that I can't do visual comparisons as well because the DRM encryption of the content is such that it prevents anyone from taking screenshots while the video content is being played.

I have been stuck with this for a while now. Would really appreciate any help I can get on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the spinner/loading element in netflix. Best way to capture spinner/loading element is to run netflix on a slow network and try to stream. You can dump the screen and get the ID of spinner element. Once you get the element ID, try searching for spinner element. If spinner element is not found, it means that video is loaded.

Comment: Unfortunately, once the video player launches, I can't fetch a single element. Not even the loader :(

Comment: Reach till player and switch off your wifi and data. Click play after that. Spinner will get loaded. Use uiautomator to find spinner.

Comment: So, let me explain in detail. I don't get a loader before the player launch. So, that part is ruled out. Second, the solution will only check if the player, one can't really know the status of the video playback in the player which I am primarily trying to achieve.

Comment: This is what I see just before video is loaded - `android.widget.TextView  Loading…` and spinner class - `android.widget.ProgressBar`

Comment: To know if video started playing, check dumpsys and see if audio is being played. It is hard to verify the video content but audio can be detected easily.

Comment: Hi, Do you got any solution for this to check video playing or not and how you are verifying the audio. Am also facing the same issue looking for solution

Comment: `adb shell dumpsys audio` - This will tell you if some audio is being played or not.

Comment: Hi @ThejusKrishna, I didnt see any difference on the command result when i play video or not. C:\Users\XXXX>adb shell dumpsys audio

Answer (score 0):

You could compare the width of the progress bar or the duration time (if showed).  Some players use to have a element or attribute on a element that's only present when content is being played.